# Python Fire doesn't parse single argument with whitespaces correctly

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, python-fire

I have a function like this -

```
def f(arg)
  print(arg)
```

trying to pass an argument with Python Fire like this -

```
f hello there
```

output -

```
hello
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked after enclosing the input within escaped quotes -

```
f \"hello there\"
```

output -

```
hello there
```

Comment: That is because without quotes it will treat `hello` as first argument and `there` as second argument. with quotes it binds together to form a single argument `hello there`

Comment: This *still* has two arguments: the escaped quotes are just regular characters, so they don't escape the space between `hello` and `there`. If this produces the output you claim, there's some context you left out of the original question.